# Most visited posts

Tags: plugins, posts

I need a plugin which shows the most visited posts. I ve looked all plugins, they are working fine but the results can manipulate with refreshing. Is there any plugin that shows unique weekly visitors.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you count the visits? Most tracking programs offer an API to get the most visited pages.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about weekly but you can use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-postviews/ to count the views on each post and then use a custom query to order the views by the post meta key 'views'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can solve your problem/request. This plugin lets you set the day-range and how many posts to show. You can i.e. show a weekly top post or "top posts the last 30 days"

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-popular-posts/